# vstfs:// protocol tries to open in VS 2012 but fails

Tags: visual-studio, visual-studio-2012, visual-studio-2017

I have VS 2012, 2015, & 2017 installed on my machine. We also have TFS 2017 locally installed. When I get an email for a code review and click the link, for everyone else it opens up VS 2015/2017 depending on the version the other people have. For me it opens VS 2012 but fails to open up the code review. I noticed if I copy and paste that vstfs//codereview/request/... link in IE it prompts me to open an external application. In this prompt it says:

Do you want to allow this website to open a program on your computer? It then shows Program: Vs 2012 and Address: vstfs:///.... For other people under the Program setting it shows the VS selector and not a specific version.

Does anyone know where I can change this setting to use the VS selector program vs VS 2012 with this vstfs:// protocol link?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Go to the Windows settings (Default App Settings in Windows 10).

[image]

Choose `Default Apps By Protocol` at the bottom of the screen.

[image]

Find the VSTS/TFS protocol handler. Set it to the Visual Studio web protocol handler.

[image]

You'll have to pick the right version by the icon (if multiple are registered). Unfortunately, the title doesn't contain the version number.

Comment: I forgot to mention windows 7 sorry. Any ideas on that OS?

Comment: Find the 'default programs' from the startmenu https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/help/18539/windows-7-change-default-programs

Comment: I think it's also under the programs and features item in  the control panel.